# Collision detection between SVG-shapes in Javafx

Tags: svg, javafx, collision-detection

I am trying to detect collision between two shapes but i doesn't work. The code detects intersection between the spriteframes, but not intersection between SVG-pahts. The SVG-paths are to rectangels and I have confirmed that they are defined correctly.

```
public boolean collide(GameObject object) 
{
    boolean collisionDetect = false;

    if(spriteFrame.getBoundsInParent().intersects(object.getSpriteFrame().getBoundsInParent()))
    { 
        Shape intersection = SVGPath.intersect(getSpriteBound(), object.getSpriteBound());

        if(intersection.getBoundsInLocal().getWidth() != -1)
        {             
               collisionDetect = true; 
        }
    }   

    if(collisionDetect)
    {
        spriteFrame.setImage(imageStates.get(1));
    }
    else
        spriteFrame.setImage(imageStates.get(0));

    return collisionDetect;
}
```

Comment: I have realized that my code had a major flaw and have changed it. It is still the same problem. The part of the code that detects intersection between the spriteframes works, but not the part that shal detect intersecton between the SVG-paths.